# Flutter- dart http library ClientException

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am doing a post request like this in flutter using **HTTP dart package** but sometimes when the network fails a **ClientException** is thrown from **IOClient** class but I don't get anything in catch block and app crashes.

```
http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body).then((response) {
  //response parsing
}).catchError((error) {
 //ClientException is never catched in this block.
});
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in `try{ ... } catch (e) { }`?

Comment: I am using Future API not async-await, I think try catch not used in Future API?

Comment: Wouldn't be too hard to try it out. If the error is thrown sync, try/catch still works. You could also try `onError` as shown in https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Comment: try-catch with await seem to be working. Not able to reproduce till now.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in `package:http/src/io_client.dart`:

> Any internal HTTP errors should be wrapped as [ClientException]s.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling#potential-problem-accidentally-mixing-synchronous-and-asynchronous-errors) this is a clear case of:

> Potential problem: accidentally mixing synchronous and asynchronous errors

To resolve this issue, you need to wrap your code in Future.sync().

> Future.sync() makes your code resilient against uncaught exceptions. If your function has a lot of code packed into it, chances are that you could be doing something dangerous without realizing it:

```
return new Future.sync(() {
  http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body).then((response) {});
});
```

> Future.sync() not only allows you to handle errors you know might occur, but also prevents errors from accidentally leaking out of your function.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the call was to an https address using Microsoft Internet Information Services as backend, in the SSL settings of the website in IIS i had mistakenly set "Client certificates: Accept" instead of "Client certificates: Ignore", setting "Ignore" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just goto your C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Pub and delete the cache folder.